# What kernels are unitary

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, integral-equations

The Fourier transform is a integral transform with kernel $e^
{−2πiξx}$. The Fourier transform is unitary in that it preserves the $L2
$ norm.

Is there a general way to show or guess that a kernel is unitary? For example, if I arbitrarily came up with a kernel $K(ξ,x) = ξ^x$ or $K(ξ,x) = ξ+x$ how would I determine if it is unitary or not. Any information about the 'space' of unitary kernels would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote the integral transform of $f$ by $F(\xi) := \int\mathrm{d}x\, f(x)K(\xi,x)$. Then, unitarity is translated $\langle F,F \rangle = \langle f,f \rangle$. If we consider the standard inner product of $L^2$, the RHS is $\langle f,f \rangle = \int\mathrm{d}x\, |f(x)|^2$, when the LHS is given by
$$
\langle F,F \rangle 
   = \int\mathrm{d}\xi\, |F(\xi)|^2 
   = \int\mathrm{d}\xi \int\mathrm{d}x_1\int \mathrm{d}x_2\, \overline{f(x_1)}f(x_2) \, \overline{K(\xi,x_1)}K(\xi,x_2),
$$
so that the condition of unitarity is written as
$$
\delta(x_1-x_2) = \int\mathrm{d}\xi\; \overline{K(\xi,x_1)}K(\xi,x_2),
$$
where $\delta$ denotes the Dirac delta function.

Comment: Thank you! Also, if you have any references where I can learn more I would appreciate it. Thanks again :)

Comment: This dirac delta condition on the kernel seems like an infinite dimensional analog of orthogonality. I wonder if this also implies that the inverse integral transform is the one with the conjugate of K and with switched arguments.

Comment: I do not think the answer makes sense. There is a serious problem with integrability. For example take $x_1=x_2.$ Then $|K(\xi,x)|^2\ge 0$ and $\int |K(\xi,x)|^2d\xi =\delta_0(x).$ It is possible iff $K(\xi,x)=0,$ $\xi$ almost everywhere, for any $x\neq 0.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc If I follow your reasoning, the Fourier transform doesn't exist, because its kernel isn't integrable. But who said the kernel needs to be integrable in the first place ? Sure I used an inner product defined initially for $L^2$, but nothing prevents us to extend it to some distributional space. Moreover, when $x_1 = x_2 = x$, the condition becomes $\int\mathrm{d}\xi\; |K(\xi,x)|^2 = \delta(0) \neq \delta_0(x)$, which actually requires the expression to diverge.

Comment: The Fourier transform does exist. The integral of $\overline{K(\xi,x)}K(\xi,y)$ should be defined properly. Do you claim that your short reasoning is sufficient for proving that the Fourier transform is unitary in the case  $K(\xi,x)=e^{-2\pi i\xi x}$ ?